# simple regex: multiple dots(.)

Tags: javascript, regex, perl

I am trying to delete everything after the .com, .etc, in a URL; to make it more meaningful

so

```
sub.domain.com/324fr9?=awerf?=awrf
```

turns to

```
sub.domain.com/
```

except the same regex doesn't work for

```
noSubDomain.com/crap?=yes123456789timesOver
```

because it only has one dot, not two!

Here's my regex(javascript):

```
/.*:\/\/.*\..*\.com/g
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/.*:\/\/(.*\.)?.*\.com/g
```

Here's the part that matters: `(.*\.)?` The question mark says that everything in that group is optional.

Comment: You guys are all so helpful its amazing!

Answer (score 7):

If you are segmenting the URL and you want to do it in perl CPAN's [URI module](http://p3rl.org/URI) might be a better option. `$uri->host` is what you want, but you can do many other things using URI module.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript has the `window.location` object which is better to use for getting URL information - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp

Else, you could just design your regex to delete everything after the `/` instead.

```
url = url.replace(/\/.*/g, "/");
```

Comment: Nope! working with innerHTML of <cite>www.GreenGoogleURLs.com</cite>

Comment: I like that way! However, will the .* cover all URL symbols? (?, =, %, /, ...)

Comment: Yes, it will. You don't even need a regex though, you could use var splitResult = url.split("/") instead, and the domain would be at splitResult[0]